# Select2 auto closes on click in WooCommerce as variation custom field

Tags: woocommerce, jquery-select2

I am trying to use Select2 4.0 in the product admin of WooCommerce 3.1.0.

I have added a custom field to variations called Color Groups, like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'add_to_variations_metabox', 10, 3 );
function add_to_variations_metabox( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

    <div>
        <p class="form-row">
            <label for="dipi_color_groups<?php echo $loop; ?>"><?php echo __( 'Color Groups', 'dipi' ); ?></label>
                <select multiple="true" id="dipi_color_groups<?php echo $loop; ?>" class="color_groups" name="dipi_color_groups[<?php echo $loop; ?>]">
                    <option>Red</option>
                    <option>Green</option>
                    <option>Blue</option>
                    <option>Beige</option>
                </select>
        </p>
    </div> <?php 
}
```

Here is my JS that makes the select a Select2.

```
    $( '#variable_product_options_inner' ).on( 'click', '.woocommerce_variation', function( e ) {

        $( "select.color_groups", $( this ) ).select2({
            tags: true,
            placeholder: "Add color groups...",
            width: "100%",
            createTag: function ( params ) {
                return {
                    id: params.term,
                    text: params.term,
                    newOption: true
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

The field displays just fine.

[image]

But when I click on it the Select2 automatically unfocuses / closes. I think it's a collision with WooCommerce's handling of Select2's, but I can't figure out how to duplicate their functionality within WC edit product.

What's the deal? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was with my click event attached to any single variations wrapping container. When clicking on the Select2 the `.woocommerce_variation` click event would fire and reset the Select2—automatically losing focus.

So I scoped the click event to the variation heading title, the `<h3>`, and only when closed. Also, I check to see if the Select2 has already been applied to avoid wasted resources or resetting the element.

```
$( '#variable_product_options_inner' ).on( 'click', '.woocommerce_variation.closed h3', function( e ) {

    // get current ddl
    $ddl = $( "select.color_groups", $( this ).parent() );

    // already a select2?
    if ( $ddl.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible" ) ) return; // get out...

    // select2-ify dropdown
    $ddl.select2({
        tags: true,
        placeholder: "Add color groups...",
        width: "100%",
        createTag: function ( params ) {
            return {
                id: params.term,
                text: params.term,
                newOption: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```